# ios 7 calculator app with decimal point

Tags: ios, uitextfield, calculator

OK Here is my Code

It now limits user input to two characters after the decimal and checks for a decimal but now it wont let me add or subtract anymore.... /sigh

```
//
//  CalculatorViewController.h
//  
//


#import "ViewController.h"

int Method;
long int SelectNumber;
float RunningTotal;


@interface CalculatorViewController : ViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *screen;

- (IBAction)backToMainViewFromCalculatorViewButton:(id)sender;


@end
```

and my .m

```
//
//  CalculatorViewController.m
//  
//


#import "CalculatorViewController.h"
BOOL isDecimal;
float resultNumber;
float displayNumber;
int operation;

NSUInteger decimalPlacesLimit = 2;


@interface CalculatorViewController ()

@end

@implementation CalculatorViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

//    self.screen.text = @"";
    isDecimal = false;
    resultNumber = 0;
    self.screen.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (IBAction)backToMainViewFromCalculatorViewButton:(id)sender {

    // Dismiss the VIEW
    // DO NOT SEGUE back
    // DO THIS
    //Going back using segue just stacks views and then soon you run out of memory and APP crashes
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)setResultWithNumber:(int)theNumber{

    if(!isDecimal){
        displayNumber *= 10;
        displayNumber += theNumber;
        self.screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", displayNumber];
    }
    else
    {
        self.screen.text = [self.screen.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", theNumber]];
    }
    displayNumber = [self.screen.text floatValue];
}

-(void)operationWithNumber:(int)theNumber{

    isDecimal = false;

    if(resultNumber == 0){
        resultNumber = displayNumber;
    }
    else{
        self.screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",resultNumber];
        switch (operation) {
            case 1:
                resultNumber += displayNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                resultNumber -= displayNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
                resultNumber = displayNumber*resultNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                resultNumber /= displayNumber;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    operation = theNumber;
    displayNumber = 0;

}
- (IBAction)AC:(id)sender {
    operation = 0;
    resultNumber = 0;
    displayNumber = 0;
    isDecimal = false;
    self.screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",0];

}
/*
- (IBAction)plus_minus:(id)sender {

    displayNumber = 0 - displayNumber;
    if(isDecimal)
        result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", displayNumber];
    else
        result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", displayNumber];

}

- (IBAction)divide:(id)sender {
    if(resultNumber != 0){
        [self operationWithNumber:operation];
        result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",resultNumber];
        displayNumber = [result.text floatValue];
        resultNumber = 0;
    }
    [self operationWithNumber:4];


}
 */
- (IBAction)seven:(id)sender
{
       NSRange range = [self.screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];

    // Search for a Period
    // If not found append one to the text
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        [self setResultWithNumber:7];
        isDecimal = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // If we allready ahve a character move on to test for .
        NSArray *explodedString = [self.screen.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSString *decimalPart = explodedString[1];

        if (decimalPart.length >= decimalPlacesLimit && ![self.screen.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            NSLog(@"textField already contains %lu decimal places", (unsigned long)decimalPlacesLimit);
            isDecimal = true;

        }
        else
        {
            isDecimal = false;
            [self setResultWithNumber:7];
        }
    }
}
- (IBAction)eight:(id)sender
{

    NSRange range = [self.screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];

    // Search for a Period
    // If not found append one to the text
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        [self setResultWithNumber:8];
    }
    else
    {
        // If we allready ahve a character move on to test for .
        NSArray *explodedString = [self.screen.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSString *decimalPart = explodedString[1];

        if (decimalPart.length >= decimalPlacesLimit && ![self.screen.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            NSLog(@"textField already contains %lu decimal places", (unsigned long)decimalPlacesLimit);
             isDecimal = true;
        }
        else
        {
            [self setResultWithNumber:8];
        }
    }
}
- (IBAction)nine:(id)sender
{

    NSRange range = [self.screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];

    // Search for a Period
    // If not found append one to the text
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        [self setResultWithNumber:9];
    }
    else
    {
        // If we allready ahve a character move on to test for .
        NSArray *explodedString = [self.screen.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSString *decimalPart = explodedString[1];

        if (decimalPart.length >= decimalPlacesLimit && ![self.screen.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            NSLog(@"textField already contains %lu decimal places", (unsigned long)decimalPlacesLimit);
              isDecimal = true;
        }
        else
        {
            [self setResultWithNumber:9];
        }
    }
}
/*
- (IBAction)multiply:(id)sender {
    if(resultNumber != 0){
        [self operationWithNumber:operation];
        result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",resultNumber];
        displayNumber = [result.text floatValue];
        resultNumber = 0;
    }
    [self operationWithNumber:3];
}
 */
- (IBAction)six:(id)sender
{
       NSRange range = [self.screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];

    // Search for a Period
    // If not found append one to the text
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        [self setResultWithNumber:6];
    }
    else
    {
        // If we allready ahve a character move on to test for .
        NSArray *explodedString = [self.screen.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSString *decimalPart = explodedString[1];

        if (decimalPart.length >= decimalPlacesLimit && ![self.screen.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            NSLog(@"textField already contains %lu decimal places", (unsigned long)decimalPlacesLimit);
            isDecimal = true;
        }
        else
        {
            [self setResultWithNumber:6];
        }
    }
}
- (IBAction)five:(id)sender
{

    NSRange range = [self.screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];

    // Search for a Period
    // If not found append one to the text
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        [self setResultWithNumber:5];
    }
    else
    {
        // If we allready ahve a character move on to test for .
        NSArray *explodedString = [self.screen.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSString *decimalPart = explodedString[1];

        if (decimalPart.length >= decimalPlacesLimit && ![self.screen.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            NSLog(@"textField already contains %lu decimal places", (unsigned long)decimalPlacesLimit);
              isDecimal = true;
        }
        else
        {
            [self setResultWithNumber:5];
        }
    }
}
- (IBAction)four:(id)sender
{

    NSRange range = [self.screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];

    // Search for a Period
    // If not found append one to the text
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        [self setResultWithNumber:4];
    }
    else
    {
        // If we allready ahve a character move on to test for .
        NSArray *explodedString = [self.screen.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSString *decimalPart = explodedString[1];

        if (decimalPart.length >= decimalPlacesLimit && ![self.screen.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            NSLog(@"textField already contains %lu decimal places", (unsigned long)decimalPlacesLimit);
              isDecimal = true;
        }
        else
        {
            [self setResultWithNumber:4];
        }
    }
}
- (IBAction)substract:(id)sender {
    if(resultNumber != 0){
        [self operationWithNumber:operation];
        self.screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",resultNumber];
        displayNumber = [self.screen.text floatValue];
        resultNumber = 0;
    }
    [self operationWithNumber:2];

}
- (IBAction)three:(id)sender
{

    NSRange range = [self.screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];

    // Search for a Period
    // If not found append one to the text
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        [self setResultWithNumber:3];
    }
    else
    {
        // If we allready ahve a character move on to test for .
        NSArray *explodedString = [self.screen.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSString *decimalPart = explodedString[1];

        if (decimalPart.length >= decimalPlacesLimit && ![self.screen.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            NSLog(@"textField already contains %lu decimal places", (unsigned long)decimalPlacesLimit);
              isDecimal = true;
        }
        else
        {
            [self setResultWithNumber:3];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)two:(id)sender
{

    NSRange range = [self.screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];

    // Search for a Period
    // If not found append one to the text
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        [self setResultWithNumber:2];
    }
    else
    {
        // If we allready ahve a character move on to test for .
        NSArray *explodedString = [self.screen.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSString *decimalPart = explodedString[1];

        if (decimalPart.length >= decimalPlacesLimit && ![self.screen.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            NSLog(@"textField already contains %lu decimal places", (unsigned long)decimalPlacesLimit);
             isDecimal = true;
        }
        else
        {
            [self setResultWithNumber:2];
        }
    }
}
- (IBAction)one:(id)sender
{

    NSRange range = [self.screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];

    // Search for a Period
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        // No period found
        isDecimal = false;
        // set the number
        [self setResultWithNumber:1];
    }
    else
    {
        // If we allready have a character move on to test for .
        NSArray *explodedString = [self.screen.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSString *decimalPart = explodedString[1];

        if (decimalPart.length >= decimalPlacesLimit && ![self.screen.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            NSLog(@"textField already contains %lu decimal places", (unsigned long)decimalPlacesLimit);
             isDecimal = true;
        }
        else
        {
            [self setResultWithNumber:1];
        }
    }}


- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    if(resultNumber != 0)
    {
        [self operationWithNumber:operation];
        self.screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",resultNumber];
        displayNumber = [self.screen.text floatValue];
        resultNumber = 0;
    }
[self operationWithNumber:1];
}

- (IBAction)zero:(id)sender
{

    NSRange range = [self.screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];

    // Search for a Period
    // If not found append one to the text
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
       [self setResultWithNumber:0];
    }
    else
    {
     // If we allready ahve a character move on to test for .
     NSArray *explodedString = [self.screen.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
     NSString *decimalPart = explodedString[1];

        if (decimalPart.length >= decimalPlacesLimit && ![self.screen.text isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            NSLog(@"textField already contains %lu decimal places", (unsigned long)decimalPlacesLimit);
             isDecimal = true;
        }
        else
        {
            [self setResultWithNumber:0];
        }
    }
}


- (IBAction)dot:(id)sender {

    isDecimal = true;
    NSRange range = [self.screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];

    // Search for a Period
    // If not found append one to the text
    if (range.location == NSNotFound)
    {
        self.screen.text = [self.screen.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
    }
    // We must have a period so now lets test for how many places after the decimal
    // and limit it to two



 //   NSLog(@"text on the way: %@", string);


    /*
    NSUInteger decimalPlacesLimit = 2;

    NSRange rangeDot = [self.screen.text rangeOfString:@"." options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange rangeComma = [self.screen.text rangeOfString:@"," options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (rangeDot.length > 0 || rangeComma.length > 0)
    {
        if([self.screen.text isEqualToString:@"."])
        {
            NSLog(@"textField already contains a separator");
        }
        else
        {
            NSArray *explodedString = [self.screen.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
            NSString *decimalPart = explodedString[1];

            if (decimalPart.length >= decimalPlacesLimit && ![self.screen.text isEqualToString:@""])
            {
                NSLog(@"textField already contains %lu decimal places", (unsigned long)decimalPlacesLimit);
            }
        }
    }
     */
}




- (IBAction)equals:(id)sender {
    [self operationWithNumber:operation];
    self.screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",resultNumber];
    displayNumber = [self.screen.text floatValue];
    resultNumber = 0;

}



- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"text on the way: %@", string);
    NSUInteger decimalPlacesLimit = 2;

    NSRange rangeDot = [textField.text rangeOfString:@"." options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange rangeComma = [textField.text rangeOfString:@"," options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    if (rangeDot.length > 0 || rangeComma.length > 0){
        if([string isEqualToString:@"."]) {
            NSLog(@"textField already contains a separator");
            return NO;
        } else {
            NSArray *explodedString = [textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
            NSString *decimalPart = explodedString[1];
            if (decimalPart.length >= decimalPlacesLimit && ![string isEqualToString:@""]) {
                NSLog(@"textField already contains %lu decimal places", (unsigned long)decimalPlacesLimit);
                return NO;
            }
        }
    }

    return YES;
}

@end
```

I cant figure out how to make sure I check for a decimal and then limit entries to no more then two places after the decimal and still be able to calculate

Any help would be appreciated

Travis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build a calculator application before. What I did was:
Use tag to identify different buttons, 0 is for button 0, 1 is for button 1 ... and 99 is for button dot. All these button triggered the same `IBAction` function, and in this function just check whether the button user pressed could be added to the `Label` (You can just use UILabel instead of UITextField here) by applying the rules you created above.
Try this code:

```
// Assume that, the number buttons have tags from 0 - 9 respectively, and dot button has tag 99
- (IBAction)onButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSRange range = [self.screen.text rangeOfString:@"."];

    BOOL canUpdateScreen = YES;
    if(range.location != NSNotFound) {
        if(sender.tag == 99) {
            // Already got dot, cannot show another dot
            canUpdateScreen = NO;
        } else {
            NSArray *explodedString = [self.screen.text componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
            if(explodedString[1].length >= decimalPlacesLimit) {
                canUpdateScreen = NO;
            }
        }
    }

    if(canUpdateScreen) {
        if(sender.tag == 99) {
            self.screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.screen.text, @"."];
        } else {
            self.screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", self.screen.text, sender.tag];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my code, just one IBAction is enough, there is no need to have IBAction for each button.

Comment: How would I adapt this as I am not using Tags, I am using IBAction buttons with numbers 0 - 9 and say a Plus and Minus IBAction button

Comment: Just set the `tag` property of each button like `button.tag = 1`

Comment: OK I will see if this works. Also is your code copyrighted? May I use it in my app if I am trying to make a calculator app to sell in the app store?

Comment: Thats fine, you can use it

Comment: I dont know how this works but thank you for letting me use your code. I hope I marked your replay as answered and gave you credit. Im new to Stack Overflow and dont know how to give points but I know your supposed to. Thank you again

Comment: sorry one last question thank you again for your help I get an error with this line  if(explodedString[1].length >= decimalPlacesLimit)
            {
                canUpdateScreen = NO;
                
            }      error is Property 'length' not found on object 'id'

Comment: This has helped me with my app as well! I do have a question though. I get the error that Travis mentioned above, that property 'length' not found on object 'id'. @Eric Qian could you help me figure this out? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I get the error that you mentioned above, that property 'length' not found on object 'id'. @Travis could you help me figure this out? Thank you.

Comment: Since the object you get from an array has a type of `id`, you need to cast it before using. For example, in your case the object you get from array is a `NSString`, so you need to cast it like `((NSString *)explodedString[1]).length`.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
-(IBAction)NUmber1:(id)sender{

    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 1;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];
}
you are erasing your current string with new INTEGER value. Try to change to

-(IBAction)NUmber1:(id)sender{
    Screen.text = [Screen.text stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
}
```

Also you need to change your SelectNumber calculation logic. I suggest you to get it from string when you really need it

```
double SelectNumber = [Screen.text doubleValue];
```

Comment: sorry maybe my question was unclear. The code I displayed can see if there is a decimal point and if you try to enter one after allready having one it wont let you. How do I check for a period and not let a user enter another one when I am using IBAction  with buttons and not the textfield keyboard that pops up when you click in the textfield.

Comment: Here is the code I have changed to try and get the decimal to not be allowed if it allredy exists and try to only allow 2 places after a decimal

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**,

The code you have posted is, **UITextFieldDelegate** method implementation. It will not be triggered, if you update the **UITextField** text through code.

**Solution**

You can use any of the below solution.

**To simplify the tasks, you can use, tag 0 to 9 for buttons 0 to 9 and some other value for “.” and "," as mentioned in another answer.**

```
// 1. Call the method (in your code) on tapping the buttons (0 - 9 and “.”) and conditionally update the UITextField.text (yourTextField.text), like

    update = [self textField:yourTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(yourTextField.text.length, 1) replacementString:yourButtonLabel];

    if (update)
    {
        // Uodate yourTextField
    }
    else
    {
        // Don’t update yourTextField
    }

// 2. Before updating yourTextField.text, check there is any decimal point or comma already in yourTextField, using

    if([yourTextField.text rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound) // Update condition to check comma if the tapped button is so
    {
        // Don’t update yourTextField
    }
    else
    {
        // Update yourTextField
    }
```

Comment: how do I post new code so you can see what I have so far?

Comment: Follow these Steps:1.Add a UITextField to your XIB; 2.Add 15 buttons 0 to 9 and decimal point,+,x,-,/,=; 3.Set tag 0 to 9 for buttons 0 to 9 and 10 for decimal point, 11-15 for operators; 4.Set IBOutlet for UITextField (displayField); 5.Set single IBAction (say -(IBAction)numberButtonTapped:(id)sender) to buttons 0-9; 6.Set IBAction for decimal point (say -(IBAction)decimalButtonTapped:(id)sender);7.Set single IBAction (say -(IBAction)operatorButtonTapped:(id)sender) to buttons +,x,-,/,=;

Comment: Below are the tags: 0 to 9 for buttons labelled 0 - 9; 10 for Decimal point; 11 for +; 12 for -; 13 for X; 14 for /; 15 for =;

Comment: to post your code, you can edit your answer or post as answer

Comment: - (IBAction)numberButtonTapped:(id)sender{displayField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", displayField.text, [sender tag]];} - (IBAction)decimalButtonTapped:(id)sender{if ([displayField.text rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound){displayField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.", displayField.text];}}

Comment: set displayField.text = @""; in viewDidLoad;

Comment: Can I post my .h and .m for you to look over?

Comment: Ok, you can post it with your question itself. Just need to edit the question, and copy the .h and .m contents with file header (name) above it.